# Jira creates duplicates

Tags: logging, duplicates, jira

We've got Jira Server version 8.1.0 and found that sometimes jira creates a valid clone of an issue (without marking that it is a clone, just two tickets), that has been created from a UI.
The main problems is that we can't trace it in logs, I simply don't know were to search the "create issue" events in the logs.

Maybe someone faced such trouble before?